# avoid useless looping shell after launching program

Tags: shell, unix

Simple question but when I write something like " evince document .pdf" my program is launched but now my actual shell window keep looping so I have to use another one
is there a way to not have an empty shell each time I launch some program from shell ?

Comment: Your shell isn't "looping".  It is "blocked" (paused) waiting for the command (e.g., "evince") to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the app into background by adding `&`:

`# evince document.pdf &`

This would return control to the shell and would keep the app running, provided it does not attempt to read/write on standard input/output. If it does, you may try using `nohup` or redirect stdio to/from /dev/null.